# ContentEditable div is not working properly in JS fiddle

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

While writing in between the sentence of the `contenteditable` div in JS fiddle, cursor position is goes to end of the sentence.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nebgcpzz/)

Comment: you are calling `setInterval` function each 500ms thats why curson position goes to end

Comment: removed setInterval also...it goes to end of the sentence

Comment: if you removed setInterval it wont go to end of the sentence

Comment: Ok..but text is not highlighting for the keywords which are defined in   words = ['oele', 'geel', 'politie', 'foo bar'];

Comment: Suggest to me for this fix

Comment: try something like, before checking for words make record of current cursor position and after parsing the words point it to the last cursor position

Answer (score 0):

Instead of timer event, use key up. I have used wait for tree seconds, after key up. You can change it to increase or decrease delay.

```
            <script>

            var changed, timer,
            lastValue = '',
            div = $('#ce'),
            words = ['oele', 'geel', 'politie', 'foo bar'];

        function markWords() {
            var html = div.html().replace(/<\/?strong>/gi, ''),
                text = html.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' '),
                exp;
            $.each(words, function(i, word) {
                exp = new RegExp('\\b(' + word + ')\\b', 'gi');
                html = html.replace(exp, function(m) {
               // console.log('WORD MATCH:', m);
                return '<strong>' + m + '</strong>';
                });
            });
            //html = html.replace('&nbsp;', ' ').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        //console.log('HTML:', html);
        //console.log('----');
            div.html(html);
        }

        //setInterval(function() {
        //    var html = div.html();
        //    if ( lastValue !== html && html ) {
        //console.log(lastValue);
        //console.log(html);
        ////console.log('----');
        //        lastValue = html;
        //        markWords();
        //        setEndOfContenteditable(div[0]);
        //    }
        //}, 500);



        $("#ce").on('keyup', function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);  //clear any running timeout on key up
            timer = setTimeout(function() { //then give it a second to see if the user is finished
                //do 
                var html = div.html();
                if ( lastValue !== html && html ) {
            // console.log(lastValue);
            // console.log(html);
            //console.log('----');
                    lastValue = html;
                    markWords();
                    setEndOfContenteditable(div[0]);
                }        

            }, 3000);
        });

        function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement)
        {
            var range,selection;
            if(document.createRange)//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
            {
                range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
                range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
                range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
                selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
                selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
                selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
            }
            else if(document.selection)//IE 8 and lower
            { 
                range = document.body.createTextRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
                range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
                range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
                range.select();//Select the range (make it the visible selection
            }
        }


        markWords();
        setEndOfContenteditable(div[0]);
        </script>
```

Comment: It is defined along with other variables like this - var changed, timer,
            lastValue = '',
            div = $('#ce'),
            words = ['oele', 'geel', 'politie', 'foo bar'];

Comment: for every 3 seconds the cursor position will goes to last of the sentence.